# Does there exist $f(x)$ such that $\int_0^x f(t) \, dt +x=1$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Does there exist $f(x)$ (continuous) such that $\int_0^x f(t) \, dt +x=1$?

My guess is that it doesn't since setting $x=0$ we obtain $0=1$. Is this assertion correct?

Comment: yes, that's right, no such $f$ exists.

Comment: No (integrable) $f$ exists for the same reason. You could also write the equation as $\int_0^x (f(t)+1)dt = 1$ which might make is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct, but we can also approach it as...

Differentiating the equation gives $f(x)+1=0 \implies f(x)=-1$.

But clearly, the function doesn't satisfy the original equation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right, indeed by another way

$$\int_0^x f(t)\,dt +x=\int_0^x (f(t)+1)\,dt=\int_0^x F(t) \, dt=1$$

which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a physicist, then you could use $f(t)=\delta(t)-1$ so$\int_0^xf(t)dt=1-x$.

Comment: What is $\delta(t)$? And why does it satisfy the condition?

Comment: $\delta(t)$ (used mainly by physicists) is called the Dirac delta function. Its definition is given by $\int_a^b\delta(t)dt=1$ if $a\le 0 \le  b$ and $=0$ otherwise.  Schwartz distribution is the rigorous math. approach.